# chunk.js not loaded in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular7

I have recently updated to ***Angular 7***.

I am working on Lazy loaded modules but I don't see `#chunk.js` anywhere in my network tab when I click the component in the lazy loaded module.

**Contact us** loads a component lazily but there is no `#chunk.js` in the network tab.

[image]

Here is how I am loading my module lazily.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ContactUsComponent } from 'src/app/modules/contactus/contactus.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from 'src/app/modules/error/error.component';
import { ContactUsRoutingModule } from 'src/app/modules/contactus/contactus-routing.module';
import { LandingComponent } from 'src/app/modules/landing/landing.component';
import { AboutUsComponent } from 'src/app/modules/aboutus/aboutus.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'landing', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'landing', component: LandingComponent },
  { path: 'aboutus', component: AboutUsComponent },
  { path: 'contactus', loadChildren: './modules/contactus/contactus.module#ContactusModule' },
  { path: '**', component: ErrorComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Am I missing out something or is the file `#chunk.js` renamed to some other file?

Comment: Can you show us your Webpack config as well, please? Actually, I would suggest go to Github and look at Todd Moto angular-lazy-load source code, first of all, Webpack config. https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-lazy-load-demo/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: As of now i am not using webpack. I am using angular-cli and `ng serve` to run/deploy my angular project.

Comment: To be able to build app by angular-cli with a chunk otpimizations, with automatically splitted modules and generated [chunk.js] files, you need run such command in CLI, for example `ng build --vendor-chunk --common-chunk` 
Here is more options https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build
By default there is no chunks after the running dev server.

Comment: Which means i won't be getting a `chunk.js` file with my default settings like in previous versions of angular!?

Comment: What I really wanted to say, it is just about configuration issue. The code looks correct. But make sure, that you don't import lazyLoaded module to the app module directly in TS via `import`

Answer (score 6):

Clarifying a little bit what Vishwajit Singh said:

There's no `chunk.js` for newer versions of Angular (7+). Instead, what Angular loads is a .js file called something like `path-to-the-module-modulename-module.js`.

This example here explains it more clearly than the one in the Angular's official website: https://web.dev/route-level-code-splitting-in-angular/

There, the author also shows the files being lazy-loaded.

Answer (score 2):

`chunk.js` does not appear in the network tab for the `angular.io`.

[lazy load example](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules) for angular 7.x.

To check if lazy loading is working correctly, navigate to the functionality and verify if the lazy module gets listed in the network tab. However, if you are using `preloadingStrategy`, the lazy module will be pre-loaded, so consider removing preloadingStrategy for testing purpose, if you are using one.